# Android: Hyperlink text with .amr sound clips

Tags: android, audio, presentation, ebooks, hyperlink

I am in the process of learning how to correctly pronounce Sanskrit verses.

I have the text in word form which can be opened by any word document reader on android

Audio version of the verses are available in .amr format (mainly due to very small occupied compared to .wav or mp3 format) and doesn't take up space on Android device

**Goal**

To be able to select a verse to play the corresponding .amr sound clip

**Tried but didn't work**

1. **Creating Ebook**  Couldn't find a way to link .amr files, besides formatting of verses is tough (compared to word document)
2. **Creating a power point presentation**. Same problem of not being able to link .amr files, besides even with .wav files, the linking didn't work well with Android OS

**Questions**

1. Is there a software by which I can hyperlink the verse to corresponding sound rendition?
2. Is there a better approach to achieve my goal?